# How to get controller/i18n object from library in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony

In **Symfony1** I do this by using:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->...
sfContext::getInstance()->getI18N()->...
```

How to get this in **Symfony2**?

**UPDATE**:
In Symfony2 this is impossible!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can do `$this->get('translator')`. More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html). Did not understand the controller part though.

**Edit:**

Sample service implementation would be,

In your class

```
namespace Your\Class\Namespace;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterFace;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class YourClass
{

    private $translator;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterFace $translator, Request $request)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aMethod(){
        $translator->trans('key');
        $session = $this->request->getSession();
    }
    //.....
}
```

Add following lines in `services.yml`

```
 my_service:
  scope: request
  class: FQCN\Of\YourClass
  arguments: [@translator, @request]
```

And then your controller you can access the class using,

```
$this->get('my_service');
```

Comment: $this works only in Controller/View. I need to get controller from library/other class. How to do this?

Comment: You have to define the class as a service container and inject the `@translator` service. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services)

Comment: OK, I try to explain in other words:
Controller executes some function Foo::bar() and in function Foo::bar() I need to access to session, for set Flash-message. Service not do this.

Comment: Yes, I understad this, but how to access to this service-controller from static class/function?